# finding a number that would equalize a set of numbers through addition or subtraction

Tags: java, arrays, math

the user must input a set of numbers of type double that we must then find the number that equalizes the numbers

here is a link to the question

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hlps5r8anhjjd8/group.jpg

I tried to solve it myself, I did the basics, but for the actual solution I don't even know where to start ?_? any hint would be much helpful

Here my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int     arr    =1000000;

        while(arr > 10000) {        
            System.out.println("enter number of students that are providing the money");
            arr = input.nextInt();                   //user input for the size of the array
        }

        double size[] = new double[arr];             //array creation , size based on user input

        for (int i =0; i<size.length;i++) {          //to input values into the array
            System.out.println("enter amount of money");
            size[i] = input.nextDouble();            //input values into the array
        }   

        for(int i=0; i<size.length;i++) {            //prints out the array
            System.out.println(size[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's your understanding of what you have to do?

Comment: thats the thing i don't even know where to start, i don't expect a solution, any hint on how to start would be of great help

Comment: You think to think, in logical terms, of how you personally would solve the problem. Forget for a moment that it's for a computer, just think how you would do it if someone asked you to solve it.

In this case, it looks like there'd be a certain value that each student would have to put in - the maximum value. Any student that put in less than that would have to pay in more.

So you need to find the maximum, then for each student who has less than that, give the difference between the maximum and what they paid.

Comment: huh.....thanx, that makes it easier, i will report later on how i am doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Read the data for a test case and put it into a suitable structure. I would probably choose a `double contribution[]` for this assignment.

Step 2. Calculate the average contribution, avg.

Step 3. Sum up the amount of money that need to change hands. sum over abs(contribution[i]-avg). **Note:** Don't forget to divide the total by 2.